# codimension of cycles/Weil divisors, definitions in EGA and Liu

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a noetherian scheme. A *cycle* on $X$ is an element $(n_x)_{x\in X}$ of the direct sum $\mathbb Z^{(X)}$, and its *support* is given by the union of all closed irreducible subsets $\overline{\{x\}}$ for which $n_x\neq 0$.

Both in [EGA IV_4, 21.6] and [Liu, Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves, 7.2.1] such a cycle is called *purely of codimension $p$* (in $X$) if its support is purely of codimension $p$ (i.e., all irreducible components are of codimension $p$).

It seems to me that this gives an undesirable definition. E.g., in $\mathbb A_k^2$, with coordinate functions $x$ and $x$, the cycle $[(x,y)] +[(x)]$ would be purely of codimension 1.

Would you agree, or am I missing something?

Comment: No. Any cycle is of the form $\sum n_x x$ where $x\in X$. The cycle is of pure codimension $p$ if $\mathrm{codim} \overline{x}=p$ for all $x$ with $n_x\neq 0$. So, the cycle you wrote down is not of pure dimension, since it has a cycle of codimension one and one of two.

Comment: I guess it's wrongly formulated, I would also use your definition.